# PHP's preg_match() to return a value in the string after a substring

Tags: php, regex

I have an issue whereby I need to return a number value that exists after a fixed sub string regardless of the other characters in the string around it. I am sort of there, because the following works.

```
$string = "Created Ticket_Id#234 (Some info)";
preg_match("/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+\s)/", $string, $res);
print $res[1];

Outputs: 234
```

But then when I get the string as follows.

```
$string = "Created Ticket_Id#234";
preg_match("/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+\s)/", $string, $res);
print $res[1];

Outputs: nothing
```

Is there a better way of doing this without looking for the white space?

Comment: None of those should be working at the moment. You have `Ticket_Id#` in the strings, but your regular expression is checking `Ticket Id_#`.  Perhaps just a typo in your testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use `\b`, the word boundary special character class, instead of `\s`.

So your pattern would be:

```
/\bTicket_Id#([0-9]+)\b/
```

Note that I pulled the special character class out of the capturing parenthesis as you need not capture it.

Also I noticed that your string had `Ticket_Id#234`, while your regex had `Ticket Id#234`. You should change the underscore in your regex based on what the case really is.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the final `\s`

Depending on whether the string or the regular expression is correct

```
/Ticket_Id#([0-9]+)/
```

or

```
/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+)/
```

This will stop at the last digit found and return the searched number.

Answer (score 0):

A few.  You could use a word boundary:

```
"/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+)\b/"
```

Check against the end of the string:

```
"/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+)(\s|$)/"
```

Or just collect all the digits:

```
"/Ticket Id_#([0-9]+)/"
```